# Passing variable from JFrame to JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, parameter-passing

Now i've spent about an hour searching the web for a solution and I either see solutions that seem too complex for me or No solution at all. I'm a student so I'm fairly new to coding so excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject. But this issue has been bugging me for way longer than I feel like it should.

After searching i settled upon the idea of placing a method inside the JFrame that just returns said variable.

Then in the JPanel I would just call this method and assign it to a variable. Then use that variable to draw the oval. This however doesn't work or more so i think it's not receiving a value because eclipse shows no issues. I try placing the getter method calls where the "x's" would be but nothing. Though when put constants in those spots like "50" it prints a circle.

Am I going about this right?? How can I pass a value from the Jframe to the Jpanel?

Code:

```
public class circ {
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     circMain  cM = new circMain();
     cM.setSize(600, 600);
     cM.setVisible(true); 
   }
}
```

jframe:

```
public class circMain extends JFrame {

private circRan circRan;
private calcBox calcBox;

double x = Math.random()*100;
double y = Math.random()*100;
    
int xfinal = (int)x;
int yfinal = (int)y;

public circMain() {
    
    super("Random Circle");
    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    circRan  = new circRan();
    calcBox  = new calcBox();
    
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    
    add(circRan, BorderLayout.NORTH);   
    add(calcBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    
}

public int getX() {
    return xfinal;
}

public int getY() {
    return yfinal;
}


}
```

jpanel:

```
public class circRan extends JPanel {

int x = getX();


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawOval(50, 50, x, x);
    setSize(300,300);
    
    
}
    

}
```

edit day 2-the get method(in circMain):

```
public int getX() {
    return xfinal;
}
```

then I place this is circRan:

```
int x = getX();
```

still not.. Welp assignment is due by the end of today feel like the solution is something simple I'm missing as it usually is.. and its aggravating.

Comment: Maybe, you need a setter in `circRan` to set the X value from `circMain`

Comment: By setter you would be implying just a method with say {x = getX();} ? And then to call setX inside the paint method? If so i tried that just now and still nothing unfortunately.

Comment: `circRan` needs to maintain it's own concept of `x`, although I'd name it `radius`, which should be supported via a "getter" to get the value and if it's to be mutated, a "setter"

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm a bit confused in, in this instance i'm trying to pull the "xfinal" variable in circMain and use it in circRan (i eventually plan to use it in another JPanel too) for the get method i just have "public int getX(){ return xfinal;  } " and then i call the method in circRan. Though even this doesn't seem to pull any value.

Comment: What you're asking is basic java 101, start by looking at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Minor detail: Java class names almost always begin with a capital letter. This is a good convention to follow.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte noted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
int x = getX();
```

is equivalent to

```
int x = this.getX();
```

i.e. your class variable `circRan.x` will get the return value of calling the function `getX()` declared for class `circRan`, which is declared for `JComponent`, a superclass of `JPanel`.

What you want to achieve is calling the function declared for instances of `circMain` (which btw overrides the `getX()` which is declared by `JFrame`s superclass `Component`). For this you'd need the instance of `circMain` you want this value of.

Alternatively, if all instances of `circMain` share this value (or if only one instance will exist) you can declare `x`,`xfinal` and `getX()` `static`. Then you can call `circMain.getX()`, calling the static function directly on the class rather than an instance. Depends on your use case, though.

Comment: Beware that `JPanel` already has a `getX` method defined, this is not going to provide the information the user is expecting.  `static` is also not a cross object communication mechanism and is great way for getting a noob into some serious trouble

Comment: Deeply thank you, I'm a student and often times we get shown a certain way of doing things and then we trick ourselves into believing said idea only works in one scenario. And what happens is I end up having to rely on a textbook more than the professor. Instancing never even crossed my mind, i suppose it may be annoying to see the newbies ask basic questions but still was great help!